# Activity Object List gets modified from dialog Object List

Tags: java, android, hashmap, android-dialog

I have an `activity` from which I created a dialog passing a `list of objects`.
In the dialog, I have modified the global `object list` data.

Problem is my activity `object list` is also modified from the dialog data manipulation. I didn't use any listener or method to do caller class data. AFAIK these are a separate object and doesn't have the same reference, So it shouldn't have changed.

Activity caller section:

```
ProductQuantityReviewDialog dialog = new ProductQuantityReviewDialog(context, salesOrderList);
dialog.show();
```

Dialog class :

```
private HashMap<Integer, OrderSalesModel> salesOrderList;

public ProductQuantityReviewDialog(@NonNull Context context, HashMap<Integer, OrderSalesModel> salesOrderList) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        this.salesOrderList = salesOrderList;
    }
```

Update: 
Tried in this way but same problem.

```
    public ProductQuantityReviewDialog(@NonNull Context context, HashMap<Integer, OrderSalesModel> salesOrderList) {
        super(context);
        this.context = context;
        orderList = new HashMap<>(salesOrderList);
       // orderList.putAll(salesOrderList);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Passing reference inside constructor makes dialog hash map refer to same address as the activity hash map.Instead of passing reference you should maintain a separate list inside dialog.

```
private Map<Integer, OrderSalesModel> mSalesOrderList;

public RetrieveInput(@NonNull Context context, HashMap<Integer, OrderSalesModel> salesOrderList) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
    copyDataToMap(salesOrderList);
}

private void copyDataToMap(HashMap<Integer, OrderSalesModel> salesOrderList) {
    mSalesOrderList = new HashMap<>();
    for (Map.Entry<Integer, OrderSalesModel> entry : salesOrderList.entrySet())
    {
        mSalesOrderList.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }
}
```

Comment: `orderList = new HashMap<>();
        orderList.putAll(salesOrderList);`

changed to this but doesn't work. Same problem

Comment: Try this updated code.This should work..your getting same problem?

Comment: tried. same thing! list value updated in the previous activity.

Comment: Try this final edited code..This will work..let me know if it is not working

Comment: same problem!  is this the reason of this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/17659412/7267105

Comment: But these are two different hashmaps right.Here I am creating a different haspmap and adding data

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/155826/discussion-between-sadiq-md-asif-and-anonymous).

Answer (score 0):

In your code . you are passing reference of the hashmap . so another hashmap is also alter .

Initialize new hashmap in you dialog and set all the value to it .

Comment: tried both! still getting the same problem. see updated section