# How does a HashMap use equals() for ArrayList<Integer>?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

I am adding an ArrayList into a HashMap and then changing the original list as follows:

```
import java.util.*;

public class HashSetCheck{

    public static void main(String[] args){
        HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, Integer> set = new HashMap<ArrayList<Integer>, Integer>();
        ArrayList<Integer> check = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        set.put(check, 0);
        check.add(1);
        ArrayList<Integer> sep = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        sep.add(1);
        System.out.println(set.containsKey(check));
        System.out.println(set.containsKey(sep));
    }

}
```

In both cases, the program prints out false.

I looked at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/934775/changing-value-after-its-placed-in-hashmap-changes-whats-inside-hashmap), and know that the HashMap is storing the reference as a key. Furthermore, the documentation states that `containsKey(key)` will check the following condition for all values `k` inside:

> (key==null ? k==null : key.equals(k))

Shouldn't the `equals()` be true for the first case. It is the same reference, and it is the same value. Otherwise, how is equals() being implemented for an ArrayList?

Comment: It's not `equals()` that's important here, it's `hashCode()` which you're changing after putting the key in the map.